# How to fix veracode CWE-80 XSS issue while downloading the file?

Tags: java, xss, outputstream, veracode

Below is my existing Java base standard code and as you can see I am simply downloading files using output stream.

I am only using the request parameter to get browser detail from the header to generate the filename and again I am decoding it.

So now I don't understand how the below code

> outputStream.write(data, 0, readed);

can leads to an XSS issue?

So, How I can resolve this issue because my output is a simple file?

```
        OutputStream outputStream = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
        InputStream fileInputStream = generateInputStreamObj(user, attachmentObj, false, httpRequest, servletContext, ipAddress);

        String userAgent = httpRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");
        String encodedFileName = generateFileName(userAgent, attachmentObj);

        int downloadBufferSize = Integer.parseInt(CacheManagement.getInstance().getSystemPropertyByAlias().get("DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE").getPropertyValue());

        httpResponse.setContentType("application/x-download");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(attachmentObj.getDocumentSize()));
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + encodedFileName + "\"");
        httpResponse.setBufferSize(downloadBufferSize);

        bufferInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        byte[] data = new byte[downloadBufferSize];
        int readed = 0;
        while ((readed = bufferInputStream.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(data, 0, readed);
        }
```

I check Stack overflow and Veracode answers but it doesn't help me.

** put a comment if you are putting this question to minus. I reviewed stackoverflow and veracode community answer but it doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Veracode is probably seeing that you're not doing any encoding and thinking it could be a XSS issue.

In this case however, there's no encoding needed because it's a file download, rather than the generation of HTML data. The result won't be interpreted by the browser as HTML with these content-type and headers so it's a false positive warning.

Answer (score 0):

Convert

```
< → &lt;

> → &gt;

' → &#39;

" → &quot;

& → &amp;
```

code:

```
public static final String stringToHtmlString(String s){
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   int n = s.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);
      switch (c) {
         case '<': sb.append("&lt;"); break;
         case '>': sb.append("&gt;"); break;
         case '&': sb.append("&amp;"); break;
         case '"': sb.append("&quot;"); break;
         default:  sb.append(c); break;
      }
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know this standard encoding practice but here I have file object not a string object and converting byte to string is also not good practice for performance and also it corrupt the file also. So is there any other suggestion for the same?

Comment: while ((readed = bufferInputStream.read(data)) != -1)
        {
           if (readed.equals('<') || readed.equals('>') .... ) {
             readed = stringToHtmlString(readed.toString())
             } 
            outputStream.write(data, 0, readed);
        }

Comment: bufferInputStream.read methods gives us integer value not string, So I can not compare  it.

Comment: I will try to compare but even it will work, it will slow the download process. I will update here if it works.

Comment: Please let me know if its work, if its work please mark question as resolved

Comment: Whenever I check readed.toString() gives me numeric number not any string characters because it will read data from bufferInputStream as per the buffer size decided, so it will not be single characters as we expect. I tried this code same as you mentioned in comment.